# Define a class that inherits from Rack::Builder

Tags: ruby, rack

I'm trying to build a `Server` class for a gem I'm building. This could define `call (env)` which would make it a rack app. However, I want to use `Rack::Builder` and map different kinds of URLs, according to my needs.

I'm not sure how to explain this but *is there a way to inherit from Rack::Builder or something?* I want to isolate the URL mappings into its own methods so I can test them in one class, so as to give meaning and isolation to it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to inherit from Rack::Builder. You can do like that.

config.ru

```
class WrapperClass
  def call(env)

    #your_url_mapping_logic env

    YourApp.new.call(env)
  end
end

run WrapperClass.new
```

or

```
class WrapperClass
  def call(env)
    #your_url_mapping_logic env

    #your app logic 
    # ....

    [status, header, body]
  end
end

run WrapperClass.new
```

Comment: That's a good point. Even though I intended to use `Rack::Builder` for the mappings, that actually sounds ok. I guess a `Router` class or something should do the trick, easier to test. Thanks, Aleksei.